# How do I change the text month/day/year in datepicker to MM/dd/yyyy in KendoUI for angular2

Tags: angular, kendo-ui

I want to change the text month/day/year in datepicker to something else, for example, MM/dd/yyyy, but I couldn't figure out how to do it.

Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

You do it by using the `[format]` attribute, like this:

```
<kendo-datepicker [format]="'dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss'" [value]="value">
</kendo-datepicker>
```

You can read about it in the documentation [here](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dateinputs/datepicker/#toc-formats).